# How to get lower and upper limit in symbolic form for a Gaussian function with an auxiliary periodic signal for the argument

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

We have a Gaussian function with an auxiliary periodic signal for the argument:

$g(x) = exp(-\frac{(x+a \cdot sin(\omega \cdot t)-b)^2}{2 \cdot c^2})$

where $x$ - argument, $b$ - shift for x-axis, $c$ - width coefficient for Gauss function, $a$ and $\omega$ - amplitude and frequency of auxiliary periodic signal, $t$ - time.

```
MaxLimit[Exp[-(x + a Sin[ω t] - b)^2/(2 c^2)], t -> Infinity]
MinLimit[Exp[-(x + a Sin[ω t] - b)^2/(2 c^2)], t -> Infinity]
```

As a result, I get the following:

[image]

How to get result for this limit in symbolic form?